# How to add an outline to text in preview?

Tags: mac, preview

I'd like to know how to add an outline to text in the current version of preview. I don't mean a box around the text, I mean an outline around the letters.

Comment: You can't modify existing text in a PDF file using Preview.app. You can use Apple Page.app to create text that has an outline.

Comment: This is not something that Preview can do: If you don't have the original document, I'd suggest using a vector drawing app, like InkScape, Vectornator,  Affinity Designer, etc. But you may have to convert the text into graphics first (ironically, that process is called 'outlining fonts'!)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do or what file type you are working with. If you have a PDF file and want to change the existing text style you will need Adobe Acrobat - the professional version.

If you want to make a few changes to some text you can import the PDF as an image into Apple Pages.app by using Copy and Paste, and then cover the original text with a text box that has the same background color, and apply your font style to your new text.